# Alias result use into where clause

Tags: sql

Hello I want to use alias result as where clause in SQL query.
Following is my SQL query.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
   `id`, 
   `number`,
   `ref_no`, 
    CONCAT(" cosid LIKE '%",REPLACE(abc_cosing, ',',"%' OR cosid LIKE '%"),"%'") AS TEST,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) 
    FROM `tbl_data_pub` 
    WHERE TEST ) AS TOTALREC FROM `tbl_data_main` as aa LEFT JOIN tbl_ref_table as bb on aa.id=bb.abc_id WHERE ref_no='12345'
```

And I am getting value of TEST as "12345%' OR cosid LIKE '%32837%' OR cosi_..." and I want to this in where clause for like. But how can I?

Comment: This seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I suspect a poorly database design behind this

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your query is invalid standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: Try HAVING clause, MySQL special trick.

Comment: Having not working i tried this.  I am using php mysql db.

Comment: to avoid this kind of issue, don't store serialized datas in your database. Consider using [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: It is possible to use alias as value in where clause in SQL query ?

Answer (score 1):

**try this:**

```
select * from
(
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
       `ing_id`, 
       `ing_cas_no`,
       `ing_cosing_ref_no`, 
       REPLACE(aig_addi_all_cosing, ',',"%' OR usf_eu_cosing_id LIKE '%") AS TEST,
       (SELECT COUNT(usf_id) 
        FROM `tbl_USFDA_published` 
        WHERE (usf_eu_cosing_id LIKE TEST)) AS USFDAREG 
FROM `tbl_ingredients` as aa 
LEFT JOIN tbl_ing_addi_cosing_ref as bb on aa.ing_id=bb.aig_ing_id
WHERE ing_cosing_ref_no='38617'
)
where TEST like '%xxx%'
```

Comment: @kishan can you check this answer

Comment: I believe OP wants to use the value of `test` in the `where` clause.

Comment: Hello i want "38617%' OR usf_eu_cosing_id LIKE '%32837%'" this into where clause not as you suggested. Ex.  WHERE (usf_eu_cosing_id LIKE '38617%' OR usf_eu_cosing_id LIKE '%32837%')) AS USFDAREG

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result from using CTE. 'Where' clause dont allow alias. Try this below query it will help.

```
;WIth CTE as (SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
       `ing_id`, 
       `ing_cas_no`,
       `ing_cosing_ref_no`, 
       REPLACE(aig_addi_all_cosing, ',',"%' OR usf_eu_cosing_id LIKE '%") AS TEST,
       (SELECT COUNT(usf_id) 
        FROM `tbl_USFDA_published` 
        WHERE (usf_eu_cosing_id LIKE TEST)) AS USFDAREG 
FROM `tbl_ingredients` as aa 
LEFT JOIN tbl_ing_addi_cosing_ref as bb on aa.ing_id=bb.aig_ing_id
WHERE ing_cosing_ref_no='38617')
select * from CTE
where TEST like  '38617%'
```

Comment: I believe OP wants to use the value of `test` in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL extends the use of the `having` clause to behave like a `where` in a non-aggregation query.  You can use this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ing_id, ing_cas_no, ing_cosing_ref_no, 
       REPLACE(aig_addi_all_cosing, ',',"%' OR usf_eu_cosing_id LIKE '%") AS TEST,
       (SELECT COUNT(usf_id) 
        FROM `tbl_USFDA_published` 
        WHERE (usf_eu_cosing_id LIKE TEST)) AS USFDAREG 
FROM tbl_ingredients i LEFT JOIN
     tbl_ing_addi_cosing_ref acr
     ON i.ing_id = acr.aig_ing_id
WHERE ing_cosing_ref_no = 38617
HAVING test LIKE '%AAA%';
```

There are good reasons why MySQL has this extension.  Two reasons are that subqueries are not allowed in the `FROM` clause for views.  And, MySQL has a tendency to materialize subqueries -- which adds extra overhead -- and this avoids that overhead.

Some other notes:

- Do not use backticks unnecessarily.  You don't need to escape the names of your columns or tables, so don't bother.
- Use *meaningful* table aliases, not random letters.  That means abbreviations for the table names.
- Qualify all column names in the query.  I haven't done this, because I have no idea where the columns are coming from.
- Presumably `ing_cosing_ref_no` is a number.  Compare the value to a *number* not a string.

Comment: Hello, I got the string with field name and values into TEST alias, so i just used to put after where clause. As you suggested it is not as per my requirement . Because i have not value but i am getting field and value both from TEST.